# DeferredWithUpdate.js Service returns promise and $$-prefixed Angular objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, eslint

I have an angular app that has a controller and a service.  The service is using **DeferredWithUpdate.js** to first use a local cached copy of data and then update after the server has returned the most recent data.

I know that the service is returning a promise first then on the resolve the actual data will be assigned to the variable.  Is there a way to defer a function in my controller until the promise is resolved and `$scope.myColours` is no longer a `promise` but rather my data?

I'm working around it now by setting `$scope.myColours = myColours.$$state.value` ESLint is saying to not use `$$` prefixed Angular objects like I currently have in my controller.

```
.service('ColourService', function($q, $http, $localStorage, $rootScope, $timeout, DeferredWithUpdate, logging) {
      this.get = function() {
        var deferred = DeferredWithUpdate.defer();

        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: new URI('/colours', $rootScope.myUrl)
        })
          .then(function(response) {
              $localStorage.cachedColours = response;
              deferred.resolve( response );
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            logging.logEvent('error', 'Failed to get a list of colours', error);
          });

        deferred.resolve( $localStorage.cachedColours );

        return( deferred.promise );
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
var myColours = ColourService.get();
$scope.colours[0].data = myColours.$$state.value;
$scope.myFunction(); //this function uses $scope.colours

myColours.update(
  function( colours ) {
    // Overwrite the programs with the "true" data from the server.
    $scope.colours[0].data = colours;
  }
);
```

Comment: What eslint rule are you using? Are you using eslint angular plugin?